# Is it possible to include citations within a `\textcolor` block?

Tags: citing, pandoc, quarto

I'm currently writing a response to reviewers document and it's required that my responses to each question be in red while the rest of the text is in black. I planned on using the `xcolor` package for this as it seemed to be the most-commonly recommended option based on other StackExchange posts. However, I would also like to include specific citations in my responses. When I do so though, they simply render as the actual text of the citation e.g., `blah blah see [@farrell2018]`. Am I correct in assuming that the usage of the `\textcolor{red}{blah blah}` environment precludes the usage of cross-references such as citations?

For further context I am writing raw LaTeX within a Quarto document, so I'm attempting to use the Pandoc citation style which is `[@farrell2018]`. I also tried generating the citation using raw LaTex e.g., `\cite{farrell2018}`, but that results in output that looks like `[?]`. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**
Using an actual .tex file and XeLaTeX (through LaTeX workshop in VS Code) I was able to get the following example document to compile correctly with the citation linked and colored in red:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{Response to Reviewers}
\author{Jack R. Leary}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Reviewer 1}

Comments from reviewer 1 \dots

\textcolor{red}{My response to the reviewer, see e.g., \cite{farrell2018}}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{references.bib}

\end{document}
```

The file `references.bib` contains the following entry:

```
@article{farrell2018,
    title = {Single-cell reconstruction of developmental trajectories during zebrafish embryogenesis},
    author = {Farrell, Jeffrey A. and Wang, Yiqun and Riesenfeld, Samantha J. and Shekhar, Karthik and Regev, Aviv and Schier, Alexander F.},
    year = {2018},
    month = {06},
    date = {2018-06},
    journal = {Science},
    pages = {eaar3131},
    volume = {360},
    number = {6392},
    doi = {10.1126/science.aar3131},
    url = {https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.aar3131},
    langid = {en}
}
```

I suppose this is a limitation with Quarto and/or Pandoc rather than LaTeX, though I'm still confused as to why using the raw LaTeX citation style in the Quarto document doesn't work correctly.

Comment: yes it should just work, `[?]` is the expected output on the first run of latex or if you have not generated a bibliography with `bibtex` unrelated to color.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! LaTeX needs many runs to get the references. Try first to rerun.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I am using `XeLaTeX` to produce the final PDF, and it is correctly performing the multiple runs necessary to generate the bibliography from my `references.bib` file.

Comment: sorry but if you show no input and show no log it is very hard to help, it is very unlikely that the citation is in any way failing because of the color, and [?] is the expected output  for initial runs, so with no other information there is not much else that anyone can say.

Comment: xelatex never does multiple runs on its own, some script may be calling it multiple times (but it would also need to call bibtex)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you cannot use `[@farrell2018]` markdown syntax inside a LaTeX command argument, that will be simply ignored  (o.e, translated to LaTeX "asis"), nor `\cite{farrell2018}` using the default `citeproc` citation method, that will not use any type of  bibtex/biber compilation to interpret that citation command.

But you can use both,  if you do not enclose the markdown cite in a latex argument to make a colored text, or if you use \cite{} with the natbib or biblatex citation-methods (and taking into account that also the `hyperref` links can change the color):

```
---
format: pdf
cite-method: biblatex
biblio-style: authoryear
hyperrefoptions: draft
bibliography: biblatex-examples.bib
---

Bla blah 
\color{red}
bla blah [@aksin] 
\color{black}
bla blah [@angenendt]
bla blah 
\textcolor{red}{bla blah \cite{baez/article}}
bla blah.


---
format: pdf
cite-method: biblatex
biblio-style: authoryear
hyperrefoptions: draft
bibliography: biblatex-examples.bib
---

Bla blah
\color{red}
bla blah [@aksin]
\color{black}
bla blah [@angenendt]
bla blah 
\textcolor{red}{bla blah \cite{baez/article}}
bla blah.
```

[image: MWE]

And (off-topic) if your document have not any LaTeX code, you can also produce the PDF via HTML with colored text (including cites) with markdown syntax to produce `div` and `span` tags, and export that to PDF using  `wkhtmltopdf` or `weasyprint` (see MWE below), but unfortunately `format: latex` will clean the code to produce than CSS styles (i.e., the tags are exported to plain text)  and therefore `format: pdf` via `pdf-engine: ***latex`  will print only black text.

```
---
format: pdf
pdf-engine: wkhtmltopdf
biblio-style: authoryear
hyperrefoptions: draft
bibliography: biblatex-examples.bib
---

Bla blah
[bla blah [@aksin]]{.class style="color: orange"}
bla blah [@angenendt] bla blah.

::: {#colored style="color: olive"}
Bla blah [@angenendt] bla blah.
:::

Bla blah [@angenendt] bla blah.

# References
```

[image: mwe2]

Note: While LaTeX can search `biblatex-examples.bib` without setting any path, Pandoc does not do that using `citeproc`. In this case the .bib file must be in the working directory, or you must add the file path in the header.